# Is there a way to create databases and tables in jawsdb on Heroku deployed app?

Tags: mysql, express, heroku

I've deployed this homework app locally.  It works fine, locally.  Once I deploy it to Heroku, and view the logs, I see
Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'jzg04w8rh30864yk.burgers' doesn't exist

I've used MySQL Workbench to connect to the Heroku db successfully, but I'm not allowed to even the SELECT command.  Workbench tells me:
Error Code: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'cvhl3g86ycqw6hse'@'96.42.208.204' for table 'user_variables_by_thread'

Repo is located here:
https://github.com/bryanmobrien/burger

I'm a student, so I understand this is probably trivial, but I've searched stack and heroku support to no avail.  I believe somehow the database that works fine locally simply isn't being created -or- I just don't know how to access and modify the database and or tables on the Heroku deployed app.

Answer (score 1):

I have had that problem recently (like 1 hour ago) and this worked for me 
1- I did export my database from phpmyadmin in sql format 
2- I downloaded HeidiSql, inside JaswDB you have a link to donwload it 
3- I installed HeidiSql and Configure my data to connect to JawsDB (when you click in JawsDb inside heroku plataform, it says your host, username and password)
Host   xxxxx
Username     xxxxx
Password    xxxxx
After that i found my database name (this will be your jzg04w8rh30864yk), and I clicked in "execute sql file", I copied my sql exported and I pasted there, after that my tables was created
And that were all, I hope that this can help you